# How to write something above math symbol?

Tags: math-mode

How to write `\geq 0` above function, for example as here:

[image]

I tried `\overset`, but it's not what I want. I wonder if it's possible to rotate `\geq` symbol for 45-90 degrees.

Comment: That might be good when discussing math at the blackboard. On a printed paper just add a note before or after the formula stating that the quantity is nonnegative.

Comment: Consider underbraces. Apart from looking better, they make more sense in terms of eye movement, because one naturally first reads the formula and then the annotation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Something like this:
\[
[h(t_j)^{\rotatebox{45}{$\scriptstyle\geq 0$}}-xyz]
\]
or this:
\[
[h\overset{\rotatebox{90}{$\scriptstyle\geq 0$}}{(t_j)}-xyz]
\]
?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 27):

I think you may be better off using `\overbrace` than creating your own math notation from scratch.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
[{\overbrace{h(t_j)}^{\ge0}}-xyz]
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

It might be a bit overkill, but you could also use `tikz` to define a command to place such notes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\note}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
        \node (X) at (0,0) {\(\displaystyle #1\)};
        \node at (X.north east) [rotate=45] {\(\scriptstyle #2\)};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\[
[\note{h(t_j)}{\geq 0} - xyz]
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your sketch seems to indicate superscript position rather than "above" so `)^{\geq0}`  or if you really must `)^{\text{\rotatebox{45}{$\geq0$}}`

With `amsmath` and `graphicx` packages loaded.